# Проверка ввода символа в input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно реализовать проверку, если в input text обнаружен символ "+" то выполнить функцию 1, если символ "+" не обнаружен, то выполнить функцию 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на `Jquery`, если надо

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){
  let val = $(this).val();
  if(val.includes('+')) {
    // Тут действия если плюс есть
    let len = (val.match(/\+/g)||[]).length;
    $('label').text(`Плюса есть | их тут целых ${len}`).css('color', 'green');
  } else {
    // А тут если нету
    $('label').text('Плюса нет').css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value=""><br>
<label></label>
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в комментах кода. Перепутаны местами)

Answer (score 0):

```
const buttonNumConfirm = document.getElementById('numConfirm');
const input = document.getElementById('inpuId'); // изменить на нужный айди

buttonNumConfirm.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (input.value.includes('+')) {
    firstFunction();
  } else {
    secondFunction();
  }
});
```

Comment: "e" - document.getelementById?

Comment: Вам нужно при каком событии сделать проверку? Когда что то вводите в input или это форма и вам нужно сделать проверку когда делаете отправку формы?

Comment: При клике на button id = "numConfirm"

Comment: отредактировал ответ, так же где комментарий в коде, нужно заменить айди на айди вашего input